# How can I launch a new window (a copy of itself) then closing each independently? In java

Tags: java, swing

I want for my program to be able to launch another copy of itself, this

```
new Thread(){
     public void run() {
             main.main(new String[]{});
     }
}.start();
```

is what I have thus far. And it works. (The main class, in main.java launches the rest of the program and serves a back-end throughout general operations).

---

Now though, when I press the close button on any of the windows, it will close them all down. The desired effect is for it only close one down.

I've tried various things with `Application.ExitListener` with no joy and I also tried opening up the new window with an alternative method:

```
main s = new main();
s.main(new String[]{});
```

I was considering getting the file path and then simply having it `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` itself from there. On this attempt, I was able to get the path fine but not the name of the .jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now though, when I press the close button on any of the windows, it will close them all down

Sounds like you are using:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

that should be:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: I had some problems implementing it as you suggested, but from what you said I've now ended up using getFrame().dispose(); in an ExitListener which I had in place anyway for something else.